# PostgreSQL equivalent for MySQL variable definition within a query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am looking for a way how to dynamically define and assign a value/-s for a variable in PostgreSQL within a query.

A very primitive MySQL example which should be translated into PostgreSQL would be as follows:

```
SELECT
  myVar1 := 15,
  myVar2 := 10,
  @myVar1 + @myVar3 AS myVar1_plus_myVar2
```

Note that everything is declared within SELECT section.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd3d738daf0523e1b59fc04ac5a97300